# How to cut values on a range and count how many occurences there are for any range?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
   client_id      order_id  order_date id_medium     revenues
0       Jack   IML-0011101  2008-05-19      9526        69.84
1       deSys  IML-0011744  2008-05-28     13868        68.32
2       deSys  IML-0011744  2008-05-28      9472         9.48
3       deSys  IML-0011744  2008-05-28      9526         6.86
4       Paul   IML-0013360  2008-06-23     21585        37.09
5       Frank  IML-0013951  2008-07-01     24539        29.61
6       Frank  IML-0013951  2008-07-01      9472        10.38
7       Jack   IML-0042758  2016-08-23   1190408        36.46
8       Frank  IML-0094979  2017-09-29   1222195        58.24
9   madinside  IML-0118214  2018-07-22   1240366        14.72
10  madinside  IML-0118214  2018-07-22   1240374         9.27
11  madinside  IML-0118214  2018-07-22   1240293        10.59
12  madinside  IML-0118214  2018-07-22   1240377        13.76
13  madinside  IML-0118214  2018-07-22   1240367        14.51
```

I would like to know:

- how many unique clients there are every year for each **"range of revenues"**, also by considering that where values for *order_id* are the same I should sum values in *revenues*. 
  That is, if I define bins of 10 euros (10 or less, between 10 and 20, between 20 and 30, and so on), how many clients every year are in each bins?
  So, in the dataframe above in year 2008 I would have 1 client (**Jack**) in bin 60-70, 1 client (**deSys**) in bin 80-90 (because he made 1 single order - IML-0011744 - of 3 mediums and then for my purpouse I must sum 68.32+9.48+6.86), and so on..
- the same thing for *order_id* but in this case I would like to count the number of orders that are unique on respect the year of order and the range of revenues.

I think I could add a column that assign a value for each record that is an approximation, based on the range desired, of the revenues value. However in this case I should assign the same value for records that have the same *order_id* and the value assigned should keep into account the sum of revenues for that same *order_id*.

---

**Expected result:**

I expect two tables, one for clients and one for orders, where for each index there is a different bins (10 or less, between 20 included and 10 excluded, between 30 included and 20 excluded, ...) and columns are the year of order.

---

UPDATE

Still working on it, I might have reached a partial result, through this code:

```
pt = ordini.groupby(["order_id","client_id","order_date"]).agg({"revenues":"sum"}).reset_index()

om = pt.groupby(["revenues"]).agg({"client_id":"nunique","order_id":"count"}).reset_index()

binn = pd.cut(om.revenues,np.arange(0,4300,100))

om.groupby(binn)[["client_id"]].count().reset_index()
```

I get something similar to this:

```
incasso_tot id_cliente
0   (0, 100]    12891
1   (100, 200]  8730
2   (200, 300]  4525
3   (300, 400]  2264
4   (400, 500]  1190
```

That should be fine, except for missing so the date information (i.e. to see values splitted per year).

Anyone could help me, please?

Comment: Can we see what you've coded thus far?

Comment: the closest thing to my expected result was to make a pivot_table, then export it on excel and make bins there  `suddivisione_per_incasso = ordini.pivot_table(values=["id_cliente"],
                                              columns="anno_ordine",
                                              index="incasso_tot",
                                              aggfunc= {"id_cliente":"nunique"},fill_value=0, margins=True).round(0)`